# Add phtml before </body> tag

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

I want to add my phtml before `</body>` tag.

I m trying this code

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="core/template" name="marketplace_player" template="magenetwork/list.phtml" />
</reference>
```

But this phtml add in wrapper class div i want that phtml exactly before `</body>` tag how can i do this?

Comment: could you explain a bit the why for this? maybe there are better solutions which can make use of this div

Answer (score 4):

You could try adding a new structural block and echo this out before the  tag where you require.

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="my_before_body" as="my_before_body" translate="label">
            <label>My before body</label>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="my_before_body">
        <block type="core/template" name="marketplace_player" template="magenetwork/list.phtml">
    </reference>
</default>
```

You would then need to echo out this new structural block in your page templates before the body tag

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_before_body') ?>
```